# PHP MYSQL retrieve data categorised

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table in my database like this.

```
  **lecturerID**   **session**   **Notes**         **studentID**

      aaa             45             something       123
      bbb             exams          something       345
      aaa             lecture        something       234
      aaa             auditions      something        234
      bbb             sdfsdf         something      234
      ccc             werwe          something        234
```

---

Now what i want is to get my data categorized with the "lecturerID".

Eg:  **lecturer id = aaa**

**sessions = 45 , lecture , auditions.**

**notes = something,something,something**

On this page all the information about all the sessions will be displayed: lecturerID should appear only once. The rest, session,
student details , notes, studentid will be different for each session.

Comment: Use `group by lecuturid` and `group_concat` the `session` and `notes`. I think `select lecuturid, group_concat(session), group_concat(notes) from table group by lecuturid` would do it (correct spellings)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Besides *"I want..."*, what is the question? What code is giving you difficulty that prevents you from successfully achieving your goal? Or have you no code at all?

Comment: how to get rows from teh table categorised by the lecturerID. sry im new and dont know the code

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is simply fetch all rows and then categorize the data via a PHP array like this:

```
$res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");

$lecturers = array();
while($line = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    if(!isset($lecturers[$line["lecturerID"]]))
        $lecturers[$line["lecturerID"]] = array();

    $lecturers[$line["lecturerID"]][] = $line;
}
```

The lecturers array will contain sub arrays containing the rows belonging to the lecturersID.

Now you can simply loop through them and create a HTML output or whatever you wish.

```
foreach($lecturers as $lecturerID => $rows){
    echo '<h1>Lecturer: '.$lecturerID.'</h1>';
    for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++){
        echo '<p>Session: '.$rows[$i]["session"].'</p>';
        echo '<p>Notes: '.$rows[$i]["Notes"].'</p>';
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT lecturerID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT session) as sessions, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT notes) as notes, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT studentID) as student_ids
FROM table  
GROUP BY lecturerID;
```

get from: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php